# I need to add the constraint in my procedure ' that is not more than two manufacture have same product '

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to add the constraint in my procedure ' that is not more than two manufacture have same product '

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Product_Manufacture( name IN VARCHAR2,product_name IN VARCHAR2)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO manufacture_by VALUES(name,product_name)
  COMMIT;
END Product_Manufacture;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SQL> create or replace procedure pm (par_name in varchar2, par_product_name in varchar2)
  2  is
  3    l_cnt number;
  4  begin
  5    select count(*)
  6      into l_cnt
  7      from manufacture_by
  8      where product_name = par_product_name;
  9
 10    if l_cnt <= 1 then
 11       insert into manufacture_by (name, product_name)
 12         values (par_name, par_product_name);
 13    else
 14       raise_application_error(-20000, 'Up to two manufacturers can have the same product');
 15    end if;
 16  end;
 17  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec pm('BMW', 'Tipo');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec pm('Audi', 'Tipo');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec pm('Fiat', 'Tipo');
BEGIN pm('Fiat', 'Tipo'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Up to two manufacturers can have the same product
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.PM", line 14
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

Comment: don't know but it not gave me error while adding two manufactures with same product-name

Comment: is it important to use `dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm)`  in exception column

Answer (score 0):

An option would be adding a Statement level trigger which checks out the condition during the occurence of the insertion and prevents the related DML statement to carry out whenever threshold is exceeded such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER chk_multiplicity
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON manufacture_by
DECLARE
  cnt    INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(COUNT(DISTINCT name))
    INTO cnt
    FROM manufacture_by
   GROUP BY product_name;

  IF cnt > 2 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20123,'At most two manufacture might have the same prod!');
  END IF;
END;
/
```